# How should "Midnight" be represented in Schema.org markup for openingHours?

Tags: schema.org, dates

I'm trying to write HTML+Microdata Schema.org for a local business that closes at midnight every night.

Below is what I currently have, but I was wondering specifically about how midnight should be represented; as I have it as 23:59:59 or should it just be 00:00:00?

```html
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/LocalBusiness">
    <h3 class="marg-t">Address & Phone</h3>
    <span itemprop="name">Business Name</span><br>
    <address itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/PostalAddress" itemprop="address">
        <span itemprop="streetAddress">150 Address St</span><br>
        <span itemprop="addressLocality">Cleveland</span>,
        <span itemprop="addressRegion">OH</span>
        <span itemprop="postalCode">43608</span>
    </address>
    <a href="tel:+14444444444"><span itemprop="telephone" content="+14444444444">(444) 444-4444</span></a>

    <h3 class="marg-t-sm">Open Hours</h3>
    <time itemprop="openingHours" datetime="Mo 8:00:00-23:59:59">Monday: 8 AM - 12 AM</time><br>
    <time itemprop="openingHours" datetime="Tu 8:00:00-23:59:59">Tuesday: 8 AM - 12 AM</time><br>
    <time itemprop="openingHours" datetime="We 8:00:00-23:59:59">Wednesday: 8 AM - 12 AM</time><br>
    <time itemprop="openingHours" datetime="Th 8:00:00-23:59:59">Thursday: 8 AM - 12 AM</time><br>
    <time itemprop="openingHours" datetime="Fr">Friday: Open 24 Hours</time><br>
    <time itemprop="openingHours" datetime="Sa">Saturday: Open 24 Hours</time><br>
    <time itemprop="openingHours" datetime="Su">Sunday: Open 24 Hours</time>
</div>
```

If I'm doing anything else wrong I wouldn't mind other suggestions as well.

Comment: Related: question on Stack Overflow: [Opening hours go over midnight](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30400998/1591669) ··· issue for Schema.org: [OpeningHoursSpecification for a place that is open past midnight](https://github.com/schemaorg/schemaorg/issues/534)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think 23:59:59 is the way to go.

Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30401896/1954068) about similar problem.

Comment: @unor & ribluc Thanks for the responses. I did see that question about going past midnight, though it didn't address specifically what to do when the business closes exactly at midnight. I think I'll just stick with 23:59:59 for now unless someone gives reason to do otherwise.